Deeplink of workchat does not work in android device
My app need to open workchat via deeplink. It is ok if I open deeplink for direct chat: https://w.m.me/{id direct user chat} but for group chat (creating by bots) using threadId, the deeplink does not work on android device( work well on ios). The
error: This username doesn't exist. Try another link. Can I know the reason and how to fix this issue?
I try many link user-thread/id or user/id or chat/id... but it still not work
